# merge two columns then group by and sorting

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle11g

All
I have the follwoing table and data, i want to merge loc1 and loc2 in one column and remove duplicate values from loc column then group it according to group_no column with sorting based on group_val ascending

```
drop table test;
create table test (loc1 number(9), loc2 number(9), group_no number(9),group_val number(9));
insert into test values(2,3,1,90);
insert into test values(2,9,1,10);
insert into test values(4,3,1,70);
insert into test values(6,8,2,20);
insert into test values(11,7,2,80);
insert into test values(20,15,2,70);
insert into test values(15,14,2,30);
insert into test values(21,31,3,50);
insert into test values(31,32,3,40);
```

the expected results are :

```
loc   group_no   
2        1            
3        1            
4        1            
9        1             
11       2
7        2 
20       2
15       2 
6        2
8        2
21       3
31       3
32       3
```

This code from Grish but without group_val , now i add it

```
select t.loc, max(t.group_no)
(
    select loc1 as loc, group_no from test

    union

    select loc2 as loc, group_no from test
) t
group by t.loc
order by 2,1


if can do it using dense_rank() over partition by group_val.
```

the loc column will sorting from top to down. accroding to group_val column

```
regards
```

Comment: Your table dat seem to have some error in data... row 8? 21, 31, 3.50? or 3, 50 ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want as result. Perhaps this?:

```
select loc, group_no 
from
(
    select loc1 as loc, group_no, group_val 
    from test

    union all

    select loc2 as loc, group_no, group_val
    from test
) t
group by group_no, loc
order by group_no asc, max(group_val) desc, loc asc ;
```

Comment: the sorting not for all memeber in groups  for all , i want sorting for each group. sorting based on group_val column

Comment: Have you tried this? It does exactly that, sort first by `group_no` and then (for rows with same group_no) by maximum of `group_val`

Comment: the last part `, loc asc` may not be what you want, check it.

Comment: Yes, but anyway that what i need. Any SQL question i will  refer to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select loc1, group_no 
from
 (
  select loc1, group_no, group_val from test
  UNION
  select loc2, group_no, group_val from test
 )
group by group_no , loc1
order by group_no, max(group_val), loc1
```

working [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/115ad/8)

EDIT:
As Codo mentioned you have conflicts in you data, so you should precise your requirements

Comment: yes woring well but i want inside the group , sorting from top to down from highest group_val column to the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try someting like the following:

Query:

```
select distinct a.loc, a.group_no
from
(select distinct loc1 as loc, group_no
  from test
union all
select distinct loc2, group_no
  from test) as a
order by a.loc asc
;
```

Results:

```
LOC    GROUP_NO
2      1
3      1
4      1
6      2
7      2
8      2
9      1
11     2
14     2
15     2
20     2
21     3
31     3
32     3
```

Comment: pls see group 2 is the sorting ok , the value for 11,2 is 80 and 15,20 is 70 so the first number is 11 or 2 then 20 or 15 and so on

Comment: Yeah I can see that, do you know why it's like that? Because my query only has `a.loc` in the `order by` clause. Even you add `group_no asc` it will still not give you the order by Group_No in ascending order. So it has to have a common column name forming after the union. So if you add `loc2 as loc` then it work similar to the perfect solution from ypercube :)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements cannot be fulfilled because they contain a conflict. If you look at the first two rows, you'll see that the result in the following data (without using *loc2*):

```
loc | group_no | group_val
  2 |        1 |        90
  2 |        1 |        10
```

According to your requirements, they are a duplicate that needs to be reduced to a single row. But then, what `group_val` value do you use for sorting: 90 or 10?

If you always use the smallest `group_val` for sorting, then the following query should work:

```
select t.loc, t.group_no from
(
    select loc1 as loc, group_no, group_val from test
    union
    select loc2 as loc, group_no, group_val from test
) t
group by t.loc, t.group_no
order by group_no, min(group_val);
```

Comment: many thanks for you, if we see for example group 1 has three group_val are 90,10,70. by logic the sorting is from highest value is 90 then 70 then 10. so the 90 group_val has two numbers is 2,3. If you ask me which one first no problem becuase both have 90 then for group_val 70 , is 4 and 3 . and for group_val 10 we have 2,9 .So the sorting must be like this 2,3,4,9 this is in group 1. and so on